# Rails 4 display output of index.html.erb as a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I am very new to Rails 4 and trying to understand how to have a partial render certain fields from index.html.erb. Am thoroughly confused.
I have been following the Depot application from Agile 4 but modifying for a registrations application.

In store, I have a partial named _listing.html.erb, which is a copy from registrations/index.html.erb in the registrations view as follows:

```
<h1>Listing</h1>
    <div id="reglist">
    <ul>
      <li>Name</li>
      <li>Age</li>
      <li>Group</li>
    </ul>
    <% @registrations.each do |r| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= r.full_name %></li>
      <li><%= r.age %></li>
      <li><%= r.group %></li>           
    </ul>                   
    <% end %>
```

.

registrations_controller.rb has:

```
def listing 
   @registrations = Registration.all
end
```

With the def listing above, if I use  @registrations = Registration.find(params[:id])  I get an error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.

store/index.html.erb has:

```
    <%= render "registrations/listing"  %>
```

If this partial contains plain text, it displays but I have no idea how to get a dynamic display of the first and last names, age and group from the Registrations table to display on a new page and be available for printing name labels.

Apologies if this is not the correct way to ask for help, I'm not sure about how to do anything like this at the moment and greatly appreciate help or direction to a beginners tutorial on partials. I've spent days on google, and SO trying to understand with no luck.

Comment: The problem is that `params` hasn't been populated when your `listing` method is called. That's probably because it wasn't called as the result of a link in a view, but was called from your top level home (`index`). What specific `id` were you expecting `params[:id]` to point to? You need to show what route gets the user to the `listing` method in the controller.